# java eclipse where are compiler errors?

Tags: java, eclipse, build

Learning Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. Version: Oxygen.1a Release (4.7.1a)
I have imported valid servlets and other classes into a web app project. When I deliberately put some bogus text into a .java class file under WEB-INF\classes\pojo, I am expecting to find the compiler error somewhere, say in the Problems view? But nothing happens. 
I check in Windows explorer and the old .class file is still there. So I delete it. I remove the bad text and restore the .java file to a valid state. Nothing happens. I try checking Project->Build Automatically and saving the file. Nothing happens.  I try UN-checking Build Automatically and creating a working set consisting of that one java file alone, then building that. Nothing happens.
How is compiling web app classes supposed to work? I have searched but haven't found the helpful help file yet.

Comment: Configure a runtime/server and add the project to the server and then build maybe

Comment: Could you post a picture of your directory layout?  It seems to me like your build path would contain a source folder and your Java file would go in there, and Eclipse would compile the class file into the classes folder.

Answer (score 0):

I moved my .java files from under \WebContent\WEB-INF\classes to \src\ and now I am seeing the expected errors listed in the Problems view.  I'll work with that and get back to you, although it may be sometime tomorrow.
Cheers.